# JSON to Datasets from delphi to fastreport

Tags: json, delphi, dataset

I'm creating an application on delphi Tokyo that can send datasets to fastreport.

The application recieve a json object that I convert in JSONArray with this code

```
    var
        ja: TJSONArray;
        jv: TJSONValue;
        o: TJSONObject;
        jp: TJSONPair;
    begin        
        jv := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue({"user":[{"USUARIO":"EMER ALVARADO", "TOKEN":"token","REPORTE":"reporte1"}],"datasets1":[{"DTEXT1":"JUAN DANIEL DE LEON","DTEXT2":"10103","DTEXT3":"UROLOGIA","DTEXT4":"3","DTEXT5":"2","DTEXT6":"NEGATIVO"}]});
        o := jv as TJSONObject;
        jp := report.Get('datasets1');
        ja := jp.JsonValue as TJSONArray;
```

I need to convert this "ja" JSONArray into a TfrxDataset in runtime.

In myreport.fr3 I have a masterdata1 and there i add a memo with the follow: [RF1.DTEXT1].

In my vcl I have a frxDBDataset with the username = FR1.

I have no idea what should I do to send the jeson as datasets to the report.

Thanks

Comment: Might want to start with [TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/REST.Response.Adapter.TRESTResponseDataSetAdapter)